# Django render doesn't works with for loop but yes without it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I have been looking for this for a while and i didn't found any solution for my issue. I'm rendering with Django according next sentence: render(request, url, context). This is my problem:

If I write manually de context of the render in the template:

> Manual template
>
> ```
>     <p>Data starting...</p>
>     <ul>
>         <li>Data1</li>
>         <li>Data2</li>
>         <li>Data3</li>
>     </ul>
> ```

The webpage looks fine and every data is shown as I want because, obviously, the output after and before rendering is:

```
     <p>Data starting...</p>
     <ul>
         <li>Data1</li>
         <li>Data2</li>     
         <li>Data3</li>    
     </ul>
```

But when I write a dynamic template to retrieve dynamic data, according next template's code:

> Dynamic template
>
> ```
>     <p>Data starting...</p>
>     <ul>
>         {% for vdom in ioDict %}
>             <li>{{ vdom }}</li>
>         {% endfor %}
>     </ul>
> ```

The output BEFORE rendering is like in the manual example:

```
     <p>Data starting...</p>
     <ul>
         <li>Data1</li>
         <li>Data2</li>     
         <li>Data3</li>    
     </ul>
```

But the output AFTER rendering is what follows:

```
     <p>Data starting...</p>
     <ul>

     </ul>
```

ioDict is a dictionary like this: {'Data1':{...}, 'Data2':{}, 'Data3':{...}}

Could someone help me? I'm really lost with this.

**Note**: I've been using loops in others templates oof my proyect and there aren't issues on them

---

**--UPDATE--**
I have two templates: the first one is to render a little html block with data of ioDict, the second one is to render the full webpage template with the little template i have described.

First render, either manual and dynamic case, has the same output (correct output). However, the output builded by dynamic template gives a not correct output if I passe it throught the 'context' argument in the second render operation.

So I don't know why dynamic template, which gives same output as manual, produce this wrong output in the second render operation.

View:

```
def loadSubModule(request):
            ...
            logMsg = "Rendering 1st template"
            context = getContext(modName, modVersion, subMod, request,
                                 assetId=assetId, userProject=currentProject,
                                 date=date, quantifier=1, mN=modName,
                                 extraArgs=extraArgs, req=request)

            url = ....

            logMsg = "Rendering 2st template"           
            return render(request, url, context)
        else:
            return HttpResponse()

    else:
        raise Http404(_('This URL is only available for AJAX requests')
```

Context: returns first render

The problem i described is in the return render.

**getContext function:**

```
def getIdsContext(**kwargs):
    
    try:
        # Data.
        data = ... //OPEN MONGODB CONNECTION TO GET DATA
        ioDict = ... //GETTING DATA

        # HTML Individual Renders.
        path = ...
        antivirusHtml = render(kwargs['req'], path + 'ids-antivirus.html',
                        {'ioDict': ioDict})
        context = {'modName': kwargs['mN'],
           'modVersion': '1.0',
           'activeSubmodule': 'ids',
           'assetId': kwargs['assetId'],
           'lastUpdatedAt': lastUpdatedAt,
           'antivirusHtml': antivirusHtml
           }

    except:
        ...

    // Note that ids-antivirus.html is the template which contains 
    // the for loop,  that one which gives a blank output
return context
```

As I said, this function returns the same if de template is manual or dynamic.

Thanks,

Mike.

Comment: If it renders the template as `<ul> </ul>`, then either `ioDict` is empty or it is missing from the template context. You haven't shown your view so we can't tell why that is.

Comment: add your `view`

Comment: I update the info, thank you both for your interest.

Comment: Your have `context = getContext(...)`, but that doesn't show what the problem is, since you haven't show `getContext`.

Comment: I update the info already, thanks. If you need something else, tell me.

Comment: I've found the solution right now. Just a line was comment, so there is not an issue with the foor loop. Thanks :))